# How to create an Windows Phone 7-like home screen launcher

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, homescreen, launcher

How would you create a Windows 7-like home screen replacement, on Android?

Comment: can you be more specific?  Need a place to get started?  Check out the sourcecode for the current launcher http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=summary

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: Would you mind giving us non-windows phone 7 users a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Launcher or Launcher2 code as per the Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way in the Windows Phone 7 platform to launch other applications, sorry! Although you could visually mimic the home screen, you would not be able to actually launch other apps.